# saving text to a file

Tags: c#, file, stream

I have a question that's driving me nuts. I have a program that saves error messages to a string in an object, then writes the string to a file in the unloadContent() thing. For some reason I keep getting Not Supported Exceptions. Here is the code in unloadContent():

```
        if (debug.getContent().Length > 0)
        {
            saveErrors save = new saveErrors();
            if (Directory.Exists(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\Errors")) ;
                Directory.CreateDirectory(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\Errors");
            save.save(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().ToString() + "\\Errors\\errorLog_" + (System.DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace("/", "_")).Replace(" ","") + ".txt");
        }
```

and here's the code in class save errors:

```
    public class saveErrors
    {
        private string mess = debug.getContent();

        public void save(string fileName)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(fileName);
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileName))
            {
                sw.Write(mess);
                sw.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm still a bit new to C#, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: What line is causing the error?

Comment: the "using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileName))" line

Comment: Try without the using, Just do `StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileName)` and see what happens

Comment: hmmm. no go. Normally I'd just add a catch but I need the logs... ahh, the joy of programming :P

Comment: Okay let me try to compile this and see what I get.

Comment: apparently it's something to do with the path's formatting

Comment: Yes I just noticed that,See my answer

Comment: I would also like to question that suspicious `;` at the end of the `if` statement in the first block of code. If that is not a typo, I would suggest removing it from your actual code.

Comment: whoops! fail. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
[Test]
public void SaveTextTest()
{
    string relativePath=@"Errors\errorLog_";
    string directoryPath = System.IO.Path.Combine( System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() , relativePath);
    var directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(directoryPath);
    if(directoryInfo.Exists==false)
        directoryInfo.Create();
    string fileName = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss") + ".txt";
    string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(directoryPath, fileName);
    string textToSave = "This will be saved";
    File.WriteAllText(path, textToSave);       
}
```

To get the [DateTime.ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) in the desired format you can pass a [formatstring](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/)

Comment: +1 for showing how to format the date without having to use the replace.

Comment: What's the concept with yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss?

Comment: Updated my answer with links describing the use of format strings.

Comment: Thanks! It's always better to know the concept of methods rather than just how to type them!

Answer (score 1):

`save.save(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().ToString() + "\\Errors\\errorLog_" + (System.DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace("/", "_")).Replace(" ", "").Replace(":", "") + ".txt");`

Change it to that. You need a `.Replace(":", "")` because `:` Is included in the date part of the code, but is invalid in a file name, so you must either remove it or replace it with something else.

As an alternative you could format the date as so:

`save.save(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().ToString() + "\\Errors\\errorLog_" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss"));`

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot! And I see the error for next time. For others: that error was that the ':' symbol cannot be in the path name. Also, \Errors\errorLog should be \\Errors\\errorLog.

Comment: Also Did you mean if(!Directory.Exists...), Being that you should be checking if it DOSEN'T exist already.